# Height returns 0 of element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, height, element

Okay, so I have a little problem with an element returning a height of 0.. It works when it's in a window resize function, but I need it to load this on the first load, the following code is under document ready, but it still won't get the height.

This element is hidden to start with, so I change the element style so it can read it's height, but for some reason it won't work.. When I check with inspect element it says height is 107px.

```
$(".extracoinfo")
    .css({
        position:   'absolute',
        visibility: 'hidden',
        display:    'block'
    });

    var modal_info_height   = $(".extracoinfo").height();

    // Remove styling
    $(".extracoinfo")
    .css({
        position:   'relative',
        visibility: 'visible',
        display:    'none'
    });
```

CSS style of element

```
display: none;
margin-top: 15px;
padding-top: 10px;
border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
```

HTML code

```
<div class="extracoinfo">

                            <h4>title</h4>
                            <p>description</p>

                            <ul class="data">

                                <li><b>till:</b> a141</li
                                ><li><b>Minimum:</b> </li
                                ><li><b>Valid :</b> test</li>

                            </ul>

                        </div>
```

I have tried with inner and outer height also, it does return the padding/margin height, but for some reason it won't get the content height with it, I know it's there..

Comment: Please add the full code, meaning the minimal HTML, CSS an JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, it's added, but I don't think it will help much, as I mentioned this code works when under a window resize function, so for some reason it doesn't know its height under document ready, which it should..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can sometimes happen if the elements contain images.

Try with `$(window).load()`instead of `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Haha yeah, that works, knew it was something to do with that. But thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```js
window.onload = function() {
 console.log($(".extracoinfo").height());
};
```